How to exit full-screen views with a single gesture
In order to exit apps' full-screen modes (i.e. video playback), you need to execute any gesture once and only then are you able to actually execute the desired gesture.
This is terrible for consistency and consistency is key when it comes to gestures, so this needs to stop.
I want a single back gesture in an app to cause the app to receive a back button event, no matter what state said app is in (full-screen or otherwise). Same for home or app switcher events. The notification bar can remain in the double-pull mode though, I think I'd prefer that actually.
I'm open for any sort of hack to make this happen as long as it's open source and applicable to AOSP Android and/or LineageOS. It wouldn't be the first time I had to patch android_frameworks_base to my will but I'd rather do this in a less invasive manner (i.e. a Magisk module).
(Specs: Fairphone 4, LineageOS 20 (Android 13), µG)
